# Python API for Google Calendar and Spreadsheets

Tags: python, gdata, google-api-python-client

I started writing some python code that adds events to a spreadsheet in Google Sheets using gdata. Everything went well and it works, but now I wanted to add these same events to a calendar and I can't figure out what I'm supposed to use.

I see that the calendar API on Google is at V3 and they suggest I install google-api-python-client. Gdata seems to be almost abandoned and I feel like I'm lost in the middle.

I would just like to be able to use one python API to add data to a calendar and a spreadsheet and if possible keeping things simple as I'm really not very good at this yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does Google API python client have an API for Google Sheets?

Comment: Sadly as far as I can tell, no. [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to continue to use gdata for sheets until a new version that supports Google API is released.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jay. I was really hoping for something more elegant. Appreciate the response